# How to configure simple authentication in Jboss7.1

Tags: java, security, jsp, jboss7.x

I am working on project written by **pure jsps(scriptlets)** without using any frameworks.

jboss version: jboss-as-7.1.0.Final

I am now trying to add simple authentication on it. So when user try to browser the jsps,  say, `http://localhost/myContextPath/hello.jsp`, it requires a login first.

**web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All Access</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

**jboss-web.xml**

```
<jboss-web>
<security-domain>other</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

**standalone.xml([jboss_home]\standalone\configuration folder)**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="usersProperties" value="users.properties"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="roles.properties"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="form-auth">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="usersProperties" value="users.properties"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="roles.properties"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
```

**users.properties(putting under webapp classes folder)**

```
user1=jboss7
```

**roles.properties(putting under webapp classes folder)**

```
user1=Admin
```

After all these modifications, I try to browser my hello jsp. I works as usual. No authentication and also no exception.

I am not sure am I going to a right direction, or security constraint is a completely different things.
Please help, thanks!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just set up the BASIC authentication for 7.1 following steps from this [article](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-security/securing-as-7-applications-using-the-applicationrealm).

Try this.

### Configuration

#### Web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All Access</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

#### jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/other</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

#### standalone.xml

Don't need to do anything if you are using **ApplicationRealm**.

### Adding user

You can add users to **ApplicationRealm** using tools provided by jboss.

From within *%JBOSS_HOME%/bin*. Use *add-user.bat (or) add-user.sh* tools.

```
C:\dev\jboss-eap-6.2\bin>add-user

What type of user do you wish to add?
 a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties)
 b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a): b

Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm 'ApplicationRealm' as discovered from the existing property files.
Username : johngalt
Password :
Re-enter Password :
What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none)[  ]: user
About to add user 'johngalt' for realm 'ApplicationRealm'
Is this correct yes/no? yes
Added user 'johngalt' to file 'C:\dev\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\application-users.properties'
Added user 'johngalt' to file 'C:\dev\jboss-eap-6.2\domain\configuration\application-users.properties'
Added user 'johngalt' with groups user to file 'C:\dev\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\application-roles.properties'
Added user 'johngalt' with groups user to file 'C:\dev\jboss-eap-6.2\domain\configuration\application-roles.properties'
Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process?
e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a Remoting connection for server to server EJB calls.
yes/no? no
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\dev\jboss-eap-6.2\bin>
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This is what works for me.
Add this to the web.xml

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HtmlAuth</web-resource-name>
        <description>application security constraints
        </description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Then add to or create a jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/other</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

add user name to jboss:
    C:\jboss\jboss-eap-6.2\bin>add-user.bat

```
What type of user do you wish to add?
 a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties)
 b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a): b

Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm 'ApplicationRealm' as discovered from the existing property files.
Username : testid
User 'testid' already exits, would you like to update the existing user password
 and roles
Is this correct yes/no? yes
Password :
Re-enter Password :
What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated
list, or leave blank for none)[user]: user,Manager
Updated user 'testid' to file 'C:\jboss\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\a
pplication-users.properties'
Updated user 'testid' to file 'C:\jboss\jboss-eap-6.2\domain\configuration\appli
cation-users.properties'
Updated user 'testid' with groups user,Manager to file 'C:\jboss\jboss-eap-6.2\s
tandalone\configuration\application-roles.properties'
Updated user 'testid' with groups user,Manager to file 'C:\jboss\jboss-eap-6.2\d
omain\configuration\application-roles.properties'
Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS pr
ocess?
 e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a Remoting conn
ection for server to server EJB calls.
yes/no? yes
To represent the user add the following to the server-identities definition <sec
ret value="TWF2ZXJpY2sjMDE=" />
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the requirement to change JBoss configurations as if you want to change the server container later, the configurations also need to be changed. Instead of this, use the session object to check the if a session already exists. If it doesn't redirect the page to login page.
This will return the current session.

`request.getSession();`

In your login page, set the current session as an attribute

`session.setAttribute('sess',request.getSession());`

Using this comparison, the user will not be able to access any other page directly.

Comment: For some reason, I want to have different access control to the webapp on different jboss. That's why I try to config it in jboss configuration. Can security-constraint also work?

Comment: from what I understand, you need to use `auth-constraint` inside the `security-constraint`. Try this link: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/J2EE_Declarative_Security_Overview-Web_Content_Security_Constraints.html