# Issue With Jboss Basic Autentication

Tags: java, jboss

Hi I have configured my application for basic authentication on Jboss7 like below.

Added the security domain in standalone.xml of Jboss like below.

```
<security-domain name="BasicAuthWebAppPolicy" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="basicSecurityWebApp-users.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="basicSecurityWebApp-roles.properties"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

In web.xml file I have the configuration like below.

```
<security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>MySecureResources</web-resource-name>
                <description>Some Description</description>
                <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
                <http-method>GET</http-method>
                <http-method>POST</http-method>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>TestRole</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
        <login-config>
            <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        </login-config>
        <security-role>
            <role-name>TestRole</role-name>
        </security-role>
```

My jboss-web.xml is having contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
            "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN"
            "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
    <jboss-web>
        <security-domain>java:/jaas/BasicAuthWebAppPolicy</security-domain>
        <context-root>/basicSecurityWebApp</context-root>
    </jboss-web>
```

Also I have the properties file added in the path WEB-INF/classes.
The user file contains **TestUserOne=TestPassword** and the role file contains 
**TestUserOne=TestRole** When I enter the suer name and password I am getting the below error in jboss logs.

> 0:18:07,162 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationMnager]
>   (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Login failure:
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginE ception:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException       at
>   org.jboss.sasl.util.UsernamePasswordHashUtil.stringToByte(UsernamePaswordHashUtil.java:86)
>          at org.jboss.sasl.util.UsernamePasswordHashUtil.generateHashedURP(UsernaePasswordHashUtil.java:131)

Please let me know what is the issue with my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The method which is causing the exception is trying to access a null object. Looking at source code of UsernamePasswordHashUtil.java [here](https://github.com/wildfly-security/jboss-sasl/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/sasl/util/UsernamePasswordHashUtil.java), "realm" is null.

You probably need to do additional configuration to make it work.
For instance, adding the following line in your web.xml :

```
<login-config>
   <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
   <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Then add users to ApplicationRealm like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378675/4849663)